# Upgrading from Grails 1.3.9 to Grails 2.2.1 produces error in domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am in the process of upgrading an app from Grails 1.3.9 to Grails 2.2.1. When I issue the run-app command, I get a long stacktrace that begins with this error and then more or less repeats it for about 400 lines:

```
2013-03-07 13:32:11.364 ERROR [            StackTrace] Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: property [sponsoringManager] not found on entity [com.mycompany.myapp.ManagerDelegate]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:713)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:457)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:153)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:170)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I think the pertinent part is this:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: property [sponsoringManager] not found on entity [com.mycompany.myapp.ManagerDelegate]
```

Here's the code for the ManagerDelegate domain class, which is a many to many join class:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp

class ManagerDelegate extends Base implements Serializable {

    static belongsTo = [sponsoringManager:User, delegate:User]

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!(other instanceof ManagerDelegate)) {
            return false
        }
        other.sponsoringManager.id == sponsoringManager.id && other.delegate.id == delegate.id
    }

    static mapping = {
        id composite: [
            'sponsoringManager',
            'delegate'
        ]
        version false
    }
}
```

As you can see, ManagerDelegate does contain a sponsoringManager property which is declared in the belongsTo statement. This worked perfectly in Grails 1.3.9.

Here is the User class:

```
class User {
    static hasMany = [sponsoringManagers: ManagerDelegate, delegates: ManagerDelegate]
    static mappedBy = [sponsoringManagers: "delegate", delegates: "sponsoringManager"]

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'uuid'
        sponsoringManagers cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
        delegates cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
    }

    ...

}
```

When I try to access the app from my browser, nothing is displayed and no log output is produced.

Comment: I'm not sure 'delegate' is a good variable name, could conflict with groovy's delegate?

Comment: What does your User domain class look like? and is this the full definition of the ManagerDelegate class or have you excluded getters/setters etc.?

Comment: @Aquatoad: I have not seen any evidence of a conflict so far, and "delegate" does not appear to be a reserved word (http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reserved+Words).

Comment: @uchamp: I have added the relevant portion of the User class. The ManagerDelegate class is displayed in its entirety.

Comment: @Ben, I migrated an app from 1.3.7 to 2.1.1 and ran into issues with getters/setters where I had used def instead of the actual object type for method return/input types. So I had to fix all the return/input types of such methods. If this was working in 1.3.9 and now isn't, I think it could be because of a similar issue. So you can try changing the method definition to boolean equals(ManagerDelegate other) OR explicitly cast 'other' inside the method after checking if it is the correct instanceof.

Comment: @uchamp: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the modification both ways, but the error remained the same.